# How to debug a class library on a SharePoint 2013 Server?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, debugging, .net

I am learning to create a forms-based authentication for claims-based web application using custom membership and role provider based on the [msdn][1] link

I will be building a class library to implement a custom authentication solution.

This is the first time experience for the creation of class library. Please let me know how could I debug and troubleshoot the issues in the project.

I'm trying to follow this guide in creating a Forms-Based Authentication for Claims-Based SharePoint 2010 Web Applications Using Custom Membership and Role Providers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg317440(v=office.14).aspx

from what i understand, the dll, when compiled and put into the GAC will be called by the web.config file in the central administration, web application and Security Token Service when user is trying to login or when the people picker is searching for the user. i want to know how do i set up a debugging mode so that i will be able to step through the code? do i need to create a blank SharePoint project and add the class files inside to deploy the solution first? Where do i deploy the solution to anyway?

Comment: Build and deploy the project in debug mode and attach to w3wp process

Comment: may i know what do you mean by deploying the project in debug mode? sorry im new so please be patient with me. :) i can build the project and under the Debug tab, i've found the w3wp process.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you have the option of building a solution in debug/release mode. It is usually present on top menu. You can also select the project. click on properties- > Select Debug and then in configuration select Debug

Comment: please bear with me, i got to the page where i see the Configuration and a drop down bar which i can choose 'Active (Debug)', 'Debug', 'Release', 'All Configuration'. so do i mean that i choose 'Debug'?. i tried to press the 'Start' button  and it throws me the error "A project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly in order to debug"

Comment: You need to set it to debug and then deploy the project.

Comment: how do i deploy the project?

Comment: Do I have to create it as a Share Point empty project first?

Answer (score 3):

In order to deploy your project from Visual Studio, go to the Solution Explorer and right click on the name of the project as shown below.

[image]

Click the Deploy Solution button to deploy the project.

Once your project is deployed, go to the page for which you have coded on the browser.

Once this is done, go to the visual studio. Select `Debug` menu. In this menu select `Attach to process`. There will be a popup that will display several processes. Select add the `w3wp` processes available and click the attach button. Place debug points as per needed.

Now,go to the browser and perform the actions like button click. When the relevant action is taken, the debug point will be hit in the visual studio and you will be able to debug it.

Comment: if it is purely a dll class library, can i still attach it to the w3wp processes ? i realized i do not need the FBA viewer which is a wsp. i can't find the w3wp proccesses

Comment: Do I have to create an empty share point project and then add in the class files?